# Firefox- alternative for Google Toolbar Translator?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, google-toolbar

As you may know, since Firefox changed it's version to 5 (right now I have Firefox 10), Google Toolbar is not compatible with firefox anymore.

I used the google toolbar quite often to translate words in internet quickly without opening a new tab to let the word translate via extra website. It was quite useful for me just to point at the word which I want to translate and just a little popup came and showed the word in my language.

Since I'm even not able to install the google toolbar (also not able with compability reporter anymore), I'm searching for a firefox addon which fullfills the same functionality (translating single words with simply pointing at them). I used quick translator long time but it seems it's also not compatible anymore. Anyone an idea?

Comment: you could look at semantix.com Dixio software and see if it does what you want. I've used it in the past and it works for other progs as well a FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inline Translator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inline-translator/)

||

[Google Dictionary and Google Translate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-dictionary-and-google-t/)

These are two inline translators that seem to be up-to-date for recent FF versions.